# JSON has no identifiers, how do i grab info from it?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

So basically I am trying to grab all these courses, throw them into a listview, and when you click on each item it will take you to another activity with a longer course description. We are to do this using JSON parsing and asynctask, if needed. I have found very little tutorials, and this class is an experiment class, I have no prior java experience, don't ask me why this is our assignment, my professor is crazy in the face.

Here's the JSON that needs to be parsed, usually I see an identifier like "name" or "number" or something that you can pull and extract but since there is none I am just completely lost at how I am supposed to grab the course number for each course. We have no books, very little examples he gave us, none of them are really pertaining to this either.

Here's the courses JSON, no array name or identifiers, yet i'm supposed to be able to magically know how to grab them seperately:

http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=true

and then each course has a course number, so getting the json for that is just adding in that course number after "course" in the URL:

http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/36-1600?json=True

36-1600 is the course number for that example.

I just would absolutely love SOME sense of direction on how to complete this. I don't need the answer just some guidance for I have been blind, deaf and dumb on this assignment and simply can not figure this out.

I have 4 questions:
-**why would they not have any identifiers in their JSON?**
-**How can I split them with no identifiers?**
-**how do i populate a listview with parsing JSON when the JSON doesn't have an array name**
-**Do you know any tutorials I can follow that can help me specifically with this?**

I am in dire need of help, thank you in advance.. I barely know where to even start.

Comment: You can just concatenate whatever identifiers you want at the beginning and end of your JSON responses and then run that through your parser.

Comment: See this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @ranjk89 that's an awesome tutorial, and i came across it, except they have identifiers in their json! That tutorial is almost useless since mine doesn't and that's literally how they are parsing their json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first resource has a list where each element is a string and the first word of the string is the course ID.

For example:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourJson);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    String courseSpec = array.get(i);
    String courseId = courseSpec.split(' ')[0]
    // and use your ID!
}
```

[String.split reference with examples](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html).

Is that enough help?

Comment: no since I am unaware of how to grab the first word of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The first link contains

```
[
    "36-1200 Computer Architecture*",
    "36-1300 Digital Image Design",
    "36-1400 Sound for Interaction",
    "36-1501 Introduction to Programming* ",
    "36-1600 Character Visualization for Games",
    "36-1950 Virtual Worlds Concepts",
    "36-2300 Digital Image Experiments",
    "36-2320 Computer Illustration*",
    "36-2350 2D Art for Games ",
    "36-2400 Sound Design for Games I*",
    "36-2550 C++ Programming I",
    "36-2600 Object Oriented Programming",
    "36-2601 Authoring Interactive Media*\t ",
    "36-2606 Interactive Advertising Campaign",
    "36-2609 Sound and Motion*",
    "36-3060 Indie Game Sprint",
    "36-3100 Navigational Interfaces *",
    "36-3110 Advanced Interfaces",
    "36-3270 Xna Game Programming",
    "36-3300 Experimental Imaging*",
    "36-3301 3D Composition for Interactive Media I",
    "36-3350 3D Digital Sculpting",
    "36-3400 Sound Design for Games 2",
    "36-3500 Programming for Games* ",
    "36-3520 Programming Data Design",
    "36-3600 IAM Team  ",
    "36-3620 Introduction to Robotics",
    "36-3710 IAM Programming Topics: Mobile Programming",
    "36-3994 Indie Team Game Project ",
    "36-3997 Large Team Game Project",
    "36-3998 Large Team Game Studio"
]
```

Its a JSONArray

```
ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("your json string");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
      String value = (String) jr.get(i);
      aa.add(value);  
}
```

To show it in ListView

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityName.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
ListView lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can use a regex to split "36-1200 Computer Architecture ".

The second link contains

```
{ // json object 
    "CourseName": "Character Visualization for Games",
    "CourseNumber": "36-1600",
    "CourseDescription": "This course is on one hand a traditional drawing course, trying to assist students in their knowledge of line, value and perspective when dealing with observational drawing, while on the other hand, it is a course designed to assist in the transition between the analog and the digital world. ",
    "Images": [ // json array images
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130135397158529174_EddieEinikis_midterm_digitalv3.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130135393832313918_QuanVu_Punica.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130135393555293438_Beryl.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130028438639598178_SebastianAsturrizaga_Final_Render02.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130028438588739570_Quintin_UshtakWarlordCharacterSheet.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130028438464245186_Nimah_Final Temp The Ferryman.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130028438437567818_Mario.Ramirez_FinalCharacter_03.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130028438296224570_KAO_03_Lieutenant Cera.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130028438220092666_JulieWilmore_Final_WithFixes.jpg",
        "http://iam.colum.edu/images/uploads/course/130028438188423042_Joi_Zara_FInal Render_01.jpg"
    ]
}
```

To parse

```
JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(" your jsonstring");
String coursename = jb.getString("CourseName");
String coursenumber = jb.getString("CourseNumber);
String coursedescription = jb.getString("CourseDescription");
```

Then parse the json array Images just like you did for the json array above.

```
JSONArray jar = jb.getJSONArray("Images");
...// loop through the array and get the link
...// once you get the links download and display images.
```

Comment: ok this actually seems like a lot of help, one thing though that i am still not understanding is the inbetween, the 2nd link I provided was only an example, when each item is clicked it it supposed to parse the JSON wtih the corresponding course number without any identifier to grab it. How do i do that?

Comment: @user3380292 you need to find a way to split the string. Use a regex to extract the number part and string part from the string.

Comment: i just dont understand why he would make us use regex something we never went over and ive been programming java for 2-3 weeks only.

Comment: @user3380292 i don't understand your comment. Can you pls clarify'

Comment: i am a game programmer who had the really smart idea of taking a mobile programming course that jammed android, iOS and Windows programming in one class. None of us have ever even seen Java before. We primarily work in c# and C++ and we are still students so still learning those even. I just don't understand why he would have us use something as complicated as regex when we can barely print out hello world.

Comment: @user3380292 i can't comment on that part. If you want to split this "36-1200 Computer Architecture " you need to use a regex or someother way. I have posted the parsing part and how you can display it in listview. Rest is for you to figure out

Answer (score 0):

The first JSON string you have is a JSON array. There is no need of identifiers, only indices.

You iterate over each element, doing whatever you want with it.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourJson);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    array.get(i); // and do whatever
}
```

Looking at the JSON array elements themselves, it seems like you'll need to parse them and split them to retrieve the course number. You can then use that in your second service.